# use c# split string with Multiple delimiters

Tags: c#, string, split

I have this string

`"abc,\u000Bdefgh,\u000Bjh,\u000Bkl"`

And i need to split the string in c#, every time `,\u000B` appears  should be a new word.

I tried this:

```
string[] newString = myString.Split(",\u000B");
```

but it didnt work, how can i do this?

Comment: That's only one delimiter that's two characters long. How does it not work?

Comment: @BoltClock - Probably since there is no overload of Split that takes just a single string as a parameter.

Comment: I know, I was prompting the OP to say more than just "it didnt work".

Comment: @BoltClock - Agreed. From the question is seems that it didn't split the string as he wanted, not that it did not compile at all.

Comment: thanks, it didnt compile it.  there is no overload of Split that takes just a single string as a parameter.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Change your split command to this:

```
string[] newString = ip.Split(new[]{",\u000B"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Or use, `StringSplitOptions.None` if you want to preserve empty entries while splitting.

Answer (score 3):

```
string[] newString = myString.Split(new string[] { ",\u000B" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Works on my machine

Answer (score 2):

```
        string myString = "abc,\u000Bdefgh,\u000Bjh,\u000Bkl";

        string[] a = myString.Split(new string[] { ",\u000B" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Comment: :) actually I was faster for a 1 minute, but never mind. The answer you accepted looks more explained

Answer (score 0):

You could use **the short character escape notation: ",\v"** instead.

```
Short   UTF-16  Description
--------------------------------------------------------------------
\'      \u0027  allow to enter a ' in a character literal, e.g. '\''
\"      \u0022  allow to enter a " in a string literal, e.g. "this is the double quote (\") character"
\\      \u005c  allow to enter a \ character in a character or string literal, e.g. '\\' or "this is the backslash (\\) character"
\0      \u0000  allow to enter the character with code 0
\a      \u0007  alarm (usually the HW beep)
\b      \u0008  back-space
\f      \u000c  form-feed (next page)
\n      \u000a  line-feed (next line)
\r      \u000d  carriage-return (move to the beginning of the line)
\t      \u0009  (horizontal-) tab
\v      \u000b  vertical-tab
```